# HeavisidePi Plot

Tags: plotting, piecewise

how could i change This Plot
 [image: This Plot]

to something like this plot [image: this plot]

each two plots are concatenation of HeavisidePi

The code for the first plot is :

```
    listID1={2,0,9,4,3,9,6,7,8};
tCje[l_]:=Table[l[[n]]*HeavisidePi[x-(n+1)],{n,1,9}];
Plot[tCje[listID1],{x,0,20},Exclusions->None]
```

Comment: Please edit to add cross-references between this and the corresponding Wolfram Community posts. It's easier to avoid duplication of effort among respondents when those are shown.

Comment: Up to the documentation, `HeavisidePi` is a distribution ("`HeavisidePi[x]` is equivalent to `HeavisideTheta[-x2]`"), not a function. In view of it, any plot is misleading here.

Answer (score 5):

```
ListLinePlot[listID1, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

Thanks to J.M. for suggesting a much better way of generating the function. This yields the same plot as below:

```
plt = Differences[ArrayPad[listID1, 1]].UnitStep[x - Range[1 + 1/2, 10 + 1/2]];
Plot[plt, {x, 0, 20}, Exclusions -> None]
```

**ORIGINAL:**

If you turn it into a piecewise function, it should work.

```
pcw = Piecewise[
  MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {tCje[listID1], 
    Join[{x <= 2.5}, 
     Table[i < x <= i + 1, {i, 2.5, 8.5, 1}], {9.5 < x}]}]]
Plot[pcw, {x, 0, 20}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

I make the first and last conditions of the piecewise to be special so that it plots over any range you want.

Comment: Here's another way to generate the function: `Differences[ArrayPad[listID1, 1]].UnitStep[x - Range[1 + 1/2, 10 + 1/2]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Oh, I like that way better, thanks!

Comment: Glad you like it, it's my preferred form as well. Of course, that version naturally maps to a `Piecewise[]` version, if that is the preferred format: `FullSimplify[Piecewise[Append[Transpose[{listID1, #1 <= x < #2 & @@@ Partition[Range[1 + 1/2, 10 + 1/2], 2, 1]}], {0, True}]] == Differences[ArrayPad[listID1, 1]].UnitStep[x - Range[1 + 1/2, 10 + 1/2]], x ∈ Reals]`

Answer (score 2):

**Using `ListStepPlot`:**

```
listID1 = {2, 0, 9, 4, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8};
data = Join[{0}, listID1]
ListStepPlot[data, "Center"]
```

[image]